# Imageview can't display a line?

Tags: android, image, imageview, line, drawable

I have a vertical line, which is a image.

I am trying to display it thru imageview, but it's not showing.
This is my imageview layout:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/game_row_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
```

And in my code, I call it:

```
Drawable image = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.line);
ImageView line = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_line);
line.setImageDrawable(image);
```

The others images are displayed correctly except this one. Do you guys have any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your imagedrawable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the attribute adjustViewBounds on your ImageView?

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game_row_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick response. I tried it, it's still not showing up.